# MySQL form input to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For my school project I need to uplate a form to my MySQL. And as i have tried almost 3 ways to upload to my Db none of them are uploaded to my database. Maybe one of you guys know what I am doing wrong.

```
<div class="row-contact row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="row wow fadeInUp">
            <form action="hazardsform.php" method="POST" class="form-contact">

              <div class="col-sm-12" style="font-size: 1.2em;">
                <p>Account gegevens</p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" > 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" placeholder="wachtwoord" > 
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 1.2em;">
                <p>Contact gegevens</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="voornaam" id="voornaam" placeholder="voornaam" > 
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" placeholder="achternaam" > 
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="adres" id="adres" placeholder="adres" > 
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="postcode" > 
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="woonplaats" id="woonplaats" placeholder="woonplaats" > 
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="geslacht" id="geslacht" placeholder="geslacht" > 
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="geboortedatum" id="geboortedatum" placeholder="GEBOORTEDATUM: DD-MM-JJJJ" >
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="telefoonnummer" id="telefoonnummer" placeholder="TELEFOONNUMMER" >
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 1.2em;">
                <p>Verzekering gegevens</p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="sofinummer" id="sofinummer" placeholder="sofinummer" >
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control form-flat" type="text" name="verzekeraar" id="verzekeraar" placeholder="verzekeraar" >
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding-top: 20px; ">
                <input style="width:90%; height: 50px;"type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>  
      </div>
```

And as for my php where all the magic happends. Keep in mind that i dont get error about database logins etc.

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'db224039_sqltest');
define('DB_USER', 'u224039_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin');
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql749int.cp.hostnet.nl');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

     if (!$db_selected) {
     die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
     }



      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
      $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
      $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
      $adres = $_POST['adres'];
      $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
      $woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
      $geslacht = $_POST['geslacht'];
      $geboortedatum = $_POST['geboortedatum'];
      $telefoon = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
      $sofinummer = $_POST['sofinummer'];
      $verzekeraar = $_POST['verzekeraar'];

      $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO client (email, wachtwoord, voornaam, achternaam, adres, postcode, woonplaats, geslacht, geboortedatum, telefoonnummer, sofinummer, verzekeraar) VALUES ('$email', '$wachtwoord', 
      '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$adres', '$postcode', '$woonplaats', '$geslacht', '$geboortedatum', '$telefoonnummer', '$sofinummer', '$verzekeraar')");


     $result = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have some error? Can you test if your page pass in php code (for example adding a creation of a file)?

Comment: @bdn02 Hi, out of nowhere it is giving me the following error: Error: Unknown column 'telefoonnummer' in 'field list'   UPDATE: already changed it. however my Nifty SD card wasn't updating from sublime :p

Comment: if you like you can see it yourself: http://wordtmijnkindgepest.nl/sql/

Comment: The only problem now is that it wants to duplicate the ID : Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @OzanKurt or PDO because the `mysql_*` extension has been deprecated as of PHP version 5.5 and deleted as of PHP version 7.0 also when handling user input use prepared statements because right now your code is very vulnerable to SQL-Injections

Comment: hi, its just a small school project so SQL injections shouldn't be a problem. However Can my MSQL  work with PDO?

Comment: Since hes a beginner mysqli works

Comment: @OzanKurt still it is better to give him an option to choose. Don't get me wrong I prefer mysqli too. But I found php in general to be easy to learn(basic things of course) if you already have some experience with coding

Answer (score 1):

your query is called result and you are trying to execute a query named sql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO client (email, wachtwoord, voornaam, achternaam, adres, postcode, woonplaats, geslacht, geboortedatum, telefoonnummer, sofinummer, verzekeraar) VALUES ('$email', '$wachtwoord', 
      '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$adres', '$postcode', '$woonplaats', '$geslacht', '$geboortedatum', '$telefoonnummer', '$sofinummer', '$verzekeraar')";
$result = mysql_query( $sql);
```

this should fix the query if you want to add a check

```
 if (! $resutl) {
echo ('seems it doesnt work');
}
```

Comment: hi, the only problem now is:  Error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY . How can make sure that Primary key is always adding +1?

Comment: @GideondeVries About what column are you talking is it some kind of ID you are having problems with? If so activate auto increment on that column

Comment: this error comes from the database when creating a new table(you are probebly using phpmyadmin) create an additional field called id and set it at auto_increment

Comment: @Heross Hahaha My God. Its working. I forgot to add auto_increment. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

First, mysql_ functions are deprecated. For best business practices going forward you should try using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Second, $telefoon is defined, but never used in your insert.

Third, you never declare $sql, and then try to execute it.

Try this instead:

```
<?php

    define('DB_NAME', 'db224039_sqltest');
    define('DB_USER', 'u224039_user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin');
    define('DB_HOST', 'mysql749int.cp.hostnet.nl');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!$link) {
         die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }

         $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

         if (!$db_selected) {
         die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
         }

          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $wachtwoord = $_POST['wachtwoord'];
          $voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
          $achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
          $adres = $_POST['adres'];
          $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
          $woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
          $geslacht = $_POST['geslacht'];
          $geboortedatum = $_POST['geboortedatum'];
          $telefoon = $_POST['telefoonnummer'];
          $sofinummer = $_POST['sofinummer'];
          $verzekeraar = $_POST['verzekeraar'];

          $sql = "INSERT INTO client (email, wachtwoord, voornaam, achternaam, adres, postcode, woonplaats, geslacht, geboortedatum, telefoonnummer, sofinummer, verzekeraar) VALUES ('$email', '$wachtwoord', 
          '$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$adres', '$postcode', '$woonplaats', '$geslacht', '$geboortedatum', '$telefoon', '$sofinummer', '$verzekeraar')";

         $result = mysql_query($sql);
         if (!$result) {
        $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error();
        die($message);
         }
        mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is defined as `$telefoon` but in the query you are using `'$telefoonnummer'`. Either change your variable name or change the one you are using in the query to match your variable name.